# How to request new circuit from within workstation?

Tags: whonix, nyx

I'm using Whonix Gateway and Workstation. I can request a new tor circuit in the Gateway via arm, I press "n". How can I do this in the Workstation terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Do once. (Install missing dependencies. Only required for Whonix 8. Will be no longer required on Whonix 9.)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telnet
```

Do every time you want a new circuit. Run `tor-ctrl` (installed by default) with `signal newnym`.

```
bash -x tor-ctrl -p notrequired -c "signal newnym"
```

If you see at the bottom of the output.

`+ sendcmd signal newnym
+ echo signal newnym
+ sleep 1
+ sendcmd QUIT
+ echo QUIT
+ sleep 1
+ STR='Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '\''^]'\''.
250 OK
250 OK'
+ vecho 'Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '\''^]'\''.
250 OK
250 OK'
+ '[' 0 -ge 1 ']'
+ echo 'Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '\''^]'\''.
250 OK
250 OK'
++ grep -c '^250 '
+ '[' 2 = 3 ']'
+ exit 1`

Then it succeeded. (`exit 1` is a bug in tor-ctrl, because it doesn't understand the double `250 OK`.)

Full disclosure: 
I am a maintainer of Whonix.

Comment: If I have a second workstation running, does that keep its circuit?

Comment: I just now wrote a separate question and answer, because the answer is too complex for a comment. See: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/if-i-change-my-circuit-in-one-workstation-will-it-be-changed-in-another-worksta/3829#3829