# If I change my circuit in one workstation, will it be changed in another workstation as well?

Tags: whonix, stream-isolation

Using [multiple Whonix-Workstations](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Multiple_Whonix-Workstations), when I change my Tor circuit in Whonix-Workstation 1 (using [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/3817/80) method for example), will my Tor circuit in Whonix-Workstation 2 be changed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little Whonix specificness here. It's similar to using many torified applications on the host, then changing circuit (using Tor Browser's New Identity feature or `arm`) and asking "are circuits changed in all applications or only in Tor Browser?"

Tor has no concept of "workstations" (neutral statement). At best it knowns that it's getting connections from separate client IPs (neutral statement).

Tor's `IsolateClientAddr` default stream isolation applies so or so. From [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual-dev.html.en).

> IsolateClientAddr
>
> Don’t share circuits with streams from a different client address. (On by default and strongly recommended; you can disable it with NoIsolateClientAddr.)
> Established connections keep their circuit. New connections will use fresh circuits.

So the answer is a bit more complex.

Circuits of long running connections (such as a long download or long IRC session) will not change their circuit - no matter from which workstation their are originating.

New connections however will use fresh circuits - no matter from which workstation their are originating.